# How to add shared email account to mail.app without integrating inbox

Tags: mail.app, email

I have mail.app setup with several personal accounts and use my inbox as a todo list by archiving completed tasks/emails. I need to add a shared email account and can't archive the inbox items otherwise other people wouldn't see them, so now I have all the shared account inbox items filling up my inbox.

Is it possible to somehow add an email account such that mail.app doesn't combine its inbox with my other inboxes? The only solution seems to be to use a separate email client.

Comment: mail.app can be given rules to move mails to given folders, based on many criteria. Mail prefs > Rules… The Inbox is already split by account, if you click the reveal icon, left of 'Inbox' itself.

Comment: I want to use the combined mailbox feature except for the shared mailbox. Using Rules wouldn't help as they would move messages out of the shared mailbox inbox so other users wouldn't see them.

Comment: then copy instead of move. I presume you're using IMAP, in that case, as it wouldn't affect a POP account.